# Visual Studio Remote Makefile project - How to set the remote target program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, remote-debugging

I have a visual studio c++ makefile project which I would like to run and debug from the IDE, however I am unsure how to set the remote debug target.
When I attempt a remote debug, the remote target be set to root build folder and I get the message

```
GDB Failed with message /home/myuser/myprojects/mytestprog is a directory.
```

I would like to run /home/myuser/myprojects/mytestprog/bin/x86_64/debug/mytestprog but am not sure which property to set for remote execution.

In a typical remote project in Visual Studio there is a $(TargetFilename) macro, however this does not exist in a makefile project, and so I would like to know what to set instead.

Could someone advise please?

Comment: When you want to debug a program you specify the program you want to debug, to the debugger.  You don't specify the directory of the project.  For one thing, a single project could create many different program so how can the tool know which one you want to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remote target program can be defined by setting the program property in the debug settings.
e.g.

```
$(RemoteOutDir)mytestprog
```